# SwiftUI do not push navigation with keyboard with Xcode 12

Tags: swiftui

I made a simple app to illustrate the issue. I have a custom Tab view, however when I click on text field and open the keyboard and my navigation tabs is being pushed up as well. I would like for navigation to be not visible (as one would expect for any app).

This image illustrates the problem:

[image]

This issue does not happen if I use native `TabView`, however I would like to use custom tabs. Does anyone figured out how to deal with it? Providing the code below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var menu = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            VStack {
                if menu == 0 {
                    FirstPage()
                } else if menu == 1 {
                    Text("all is good")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
            CustomTabs(menu: $menu)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabs: View {
    @Binding var menu: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Nav1")
                .onTapGesture{
                    self.menu = 0
                }
            Spacer()
            Text("Nav2")
                .onTapGesture{
                    self.menu = 1
                }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(.red))
    }
}

struct FirstPage: View {
    @State var mood: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("How are you?")
            TextField("answer textfield", text: $mood)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution/work-around would be to embed the `CustomTabs` in a `VStack` with a `Spacer` which pushes the tabs down even when the keyboard appears and then put this Stack in front of your view via `ZStack`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var menu = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            VStack {
                if menu == 0 {
                    FirstPage()
                } else if menu == 1 {
                    Text("all is good")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
            VStack {
                Spacer(minLength: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 70)
                CustomTabs(menu: $menu)
                    .frame(height: 70)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity I just decided to set the tabs height to 70. A more beautiful solution would be to use GeometryReader.

Comment: Interesting solution! However it doesn't seem to work if I put ScrollView inside VStack with the content =/